# How to update functions in java without editing/inheriting the file

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a use-case to update java tomcat library for my project. We do this by going to individual functions in each of the classes and editing them. This becomes a pain because we have to perform same activity with every tomcat release. Is there a way to update a function of a class without editing them directly or inheriting them?

Example ->
library -> class A -> function f1

Add a behavior change to function f1 of class A (without extending).
Now when function f1 is called, it's definition is that of a new one.

I am not sure how to search for answer to this question.

Edit 1: Adding more details

1. Changes are specific to project, submitting a patch to tomcat itself won't work.
2. Changes are made to almost 6-7 generated jars (catalina, coyote, servlet etc)
3. I could think of crude approach to edit those files via a script, but I thought I would ask for a better alternatives first.

Comment: You could submit a patch to the Tomcat project itself... Otherwise, you're basically maintaining a fork, and have to edit each release, yes. Without more details, it's hard to answer for your use case. Maybe "Composition over Inheritance" helps you

Comment: @OneCricketeer hi, added more details and replyin edit.

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify the Tomcat-delivered files. Currently you are perceiving the pain of applying the wrong process.

Instead, create your own library that implements the same interface as Tomcat's library. Internally, run your own code or just call the functions that are supplied by the original one from Tomcat.

Finally configure Tomcat such that it would make use of your library instead of the builtin one. This should be possible via server.xml, but you did not disclose exactly which library and why you need to replace. Hence your good friend should be the [Tomcat configuration reference documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could do this with some "bytecode engineering" that rewrites or replaces bytecodes for specific methods at build or run time.

In practice, it would be simpler to make the changes at the source code level; e.g. by using a patch script, or by using GIT merging or similar.

In either case, the process is going to be fragile; i.e. future changes to the Tomcat codebase may mean your procedure for patching may stop working.

---

<sup>I won't comment on whether what you are doing is a good idea.  That will depend on what your changes are doing and whether there are viable alternatives.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I will read about bytecode engineering. Yeah, I actually thought if there isn't an elegant solution, I would write a script to update the code and then proof read it manually.

Comment: No, there isn't an elegant solution.  This is inelegant even in languages like Python and JavaScript that support (so-called) [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).